# Merge a list of dataframes to create one dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of 18 data frames:

```
dfList = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6.....df18]
```

All of the data frames have a common id column so it's easy to join them each together with pd.merge 2 at a time. Is there a way to join them all at once so that dfList comes back as a single dataframe?

Comment: could you elaborate on the looping option? sounds like what I'd be looking for

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), but first set index of each `DataFrame` by common column:

```
dfs = [df.set_index('id') for df in dfList]
print pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

If need join by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
from functools import reduce
df = reduce(lambda df1,df2: pd.merge(df1,df2,on='id'), dfList)
```

Comment: `pd.concat(dfList, axis=1)` combined them all, but each df had it's own line (so every id was repeated 18 times)

Comment: I tried to write as variable: `sdf = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)` and got `TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"` Don't get it.