# pandas join two json columns and combine them but results in a key error

Tags: pandas

I am attempting to join two json columns using Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

students_df = pd.DataFrame([['Jay',16,'Soccer'],['Jay',26,'Soccer'],
                   ['Jack',19, 'FootBall'],
                   ['Dorsey',19, 'Dining'],
                   ['Mark',18, 'Swimming']],
                  columns = ['Name','Age', 'Sport'])
                  
courses_df = pd.DataFrame([['Jay','MS'],
                   ['Jay','Music'],
                   ['Dorsey','Music'],
                   ['Dorsey', 'Piano'],
                   ['Mark','MS']],
                  columns = ['Name','Course'])
                  
students_df_json = students_df.groupby(['Name']).apply(lambda x: x.drop(columns='Name').to_json(orient='records')).reset_index(name="students_json")          
courses_df_json = courses_df.groupby(['Name']).apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient='records')).reset_index(name="courses_json")
```

I want to join the two dataframes
and then concatenate the two json columns students_json and courses_json

```
pd.merge(students_df_json , courses_df_json, on="Name")
```

My try

```
pd.merge(students_df_json, courses_df_json, on="Name").apply(        
     lambda x: x["students_json"] + x["courses_json"]                 
 )
```

But this results in a key error

KeyError: 'students_json'

Also I have another question what is the variable x referring to in the lambda ?

Comment: `apply(..., axis=1)` to apply lambda for each row

Comment: Hi Psidom Thanks it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vectorized join dont use `apply`, only use `+` with `Series`:

```
df = pd.merge(students_df_json, courses_df_json, on="Name", how='left')
s = df["students_json"] + df["courses_json"]
```

Comment: can we merge multiple data frames on a key and tell pandas that i need a left join ?

Comment: @jhon.smith - How many DataFrames? It is list of DataFrames?

Comment: @jhon.smith - something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38978237/2901002) ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the `lambda x` refers to the function input variable `x`. In your case when you apply the function on the dataframe it is by default on the `axis=0` which is row wise values.

For your requirement I believe you need to apply through `axis=1` for column wise values as mentioned below.

```py
pd.merge(students_df_json, courses_df_json, on="Name").apply(        
     lambda x: x["students_json"] + x["courses_json"], axis=1
 )
```

Comment: Hi is there a way to annotate the lambda x: as a data frame so intellisense can help me?For example in python we can annotate a variable name:str

Comment: In lambda x : x is not a dataframe type, it is pandas series instead and not sure how to annotate non native datatypes of Python in intellisense