# Append Columns From Multiple CSVs into One File - Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, indexing, output

I am trying to use the Pandas library to append columns multiple CSV files of the same format into a single file, but cannot seem to get the syntax correct in my script.  Here are the CSVs I am trying to parse, all located in the same file path, and the desired output csv file:

CSV #1:

```
Application, Classifier
Request, 14
Timeframe, 3
Adjudication, 10
```

CSV #2:

```
Application, Processor
Request, 15
Timeframe, 5
Adjudication, 20
```

CSV #3:

```
Application, Receiver
Request, 12
Timeframe, 10
Adjudication, 21
```

Desired CSV:

```
Application, Classifier, Processor, Receiver
Request, 14, 15, 12
Timeframe, 3, 5, 10
Adjudication, 10, 20, 21
```

Below is the code I am trying to implement to write to the desired CSV to a single file:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\'
extension = '.csv'

files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith(extension)]

dfs = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file))
    dfs.append(df)
    
df1 = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)).dropna() 
df2.to_csv('df_results.csv', index = False)
```

I feel there must be something small I am missing to append each column of the individual CSVs to a single output, any assistance is most appreciated!

Comment: I would imagine that using the [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) function would be more appropriate than concat since you have a common column of keys that you are merging on ?

Comment: To concat horizontally you need `axis=1` and `keys=['Application']`. You also need to do it ***after*** the loop is finished all it's iterations, currently you concat every time you read a file. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: @KaranShishoo MERGE only takes two dataframes, CONCAT with axis=1 can take any number.

Comment: @MatBailie look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38978237/6620283) it works on lists as well if you setup the lambda function and reduce but you are correct the concat is far more succinct

Comment: @KaranShishoo That shows my point. In that answer, CONCAT gets called once, but MERGE gets called repeatedly for each element (REDUCE is handling the list, not MERGE)

Comment: `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(x, index_col=0) for x in list_of_files if x.endswith('.csv')], axis=1).reset_index()`

Comment: @MatBailie Oops, wrong link. I updated. If you're thinking of a better one feel free to change.

Comment: Thanks, @all, I appreciate the feedback.  I reopened/edited the last two lines of the code snippet per the feedback below, but still cannot produce the desired output.  I feel I am getting closer to the solution, but any direct edits to reproduce the correct output would be great!

Comment: The post has been updated with a viable solution to generate the desired output CSV file.